# SSH Tunneling for Munin

Tags: ssh, munin, tunnel

I had at home an NAS and in the datacenter a Server. I make an SSH Tunnel with the following command:

```
autossh -fN -M20404 -R 1337:localhost:22 user@server
```

(from the nas to the server)
Its working and I can access the NAS.
Now, I want access the munin-node, also I make a new tunnel from the server to the nas:

```
ssh -N -R 49499:localhost:4949 localhost -p 1337
```

but if I make an nmap localhost -p 49499 the port is closed and i cant access the munin-node.

I don't know why and I am very happy about your help.

Comment: To be sure I understand well: The autossh command is executed on the NAS, the ssh command is executed on the server, and the nmap command is executed on the NAS? Is the munin-node also on the server?

Comment: autossh executed on the nas, ssh executed on the server, nmap executed on the server - munin-node runs on nas and the munin-server on the server :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to access your munin-node running on your NAS from your server, you should use in your `ssh` command a direct port forwarding with `-L` instead of a reverse port forwarding with `-R`:

On the NAS:

```
nas $ autossh -fN -M20404 -R 1337:localhost:22 user@server
```

On the server:

```
server $ ssh -N -L 49499:localhost:4949 localhost -p 1337
```

Then from your server, `telnet localhost 49499` should connect to your munin-node on the NAS.

If you don't need your `autossh` command for something else, you could simplify everything with only one command on your NAS:

```
nas $ autossh -fN -M20404 -R 49499:localhost:4949 user@server
```

Then again on the server, you can access the munin-node of your NAS with `telnet localhost 49499` as well, through the SSH tunnel.

Comment: You are right! I am so stupid. Its so easy! Many thanks!